# Android sql case sensitive not working in rawQuery?

Tags: android, sqlite

rawQuery string search give me all results without case sensitive.

my code is

```
    String gg="mt";   
    String cnql = "SELECT DISTINCT sinhala FROM jgd WHERE sinhala LIKE '"+gg+"%'   LIMIT 0,40";  
    Cursor   cg=cn.rawQuery(cnql, null);
```

it outputs

"mT examles"
"mt examles"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIKE` is case insensitive by default. You can change it to case sensitive with

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;
```

(Use `execSQL()` to execute that pragma.)